# Type to represent a string which is not empty or spaces in F#

Tags: f#

I love the simplicity of types like

```
type Code = Code of string
```

But I would like to put some restrictions on string (in this case - do not allow empty of spaces-only strings). Something like

```
type nonemptystring = ???
type Code = Code of nonemptystring
```

How do I define this type in F# idiomatic way? I know I can make it a class with constructor or a restricted module with factory function, but is there an easy way?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-more-semantic-types/ - the section "Modeling constrained strings with types". You probably will need do something like this

Comment: @Petr I saw this post but I find this solution somewhat over complicated. Thanks for the link anyway.

Comment: Yes, I agree that that post is a bit complicated. I have some better examples here: https://gist.github.com/swlaschin/54cfff886669ccab895a . As others have pointed out, the solutions are not particularly elegant. OTOH, you'd have to do something similar in OO code as well.

Answer (score 9):

A `string` is essentially a sequence of `char` values (in Haskell, BTW, `String` *is* a type alias for `[Char]`). A more general question, then, would be if it's possible to statically declare a list as having a given size.

Such a language feature is know as [Dependent Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), and F# doesn't have it. The short answer, therefore, is that this is not possible to do in a declarative fashion.

The easiest, and probably also most idiomatic, way, then, would be to define `Code` as a single-case Discriminated Union:

```
type Code = Code of string
```

In the module that defines `Code`, you'd also define a function that clients can use to create `Code` values:

```
let tryCreateCode candidate =
    if System.String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace candidate
    then None
    else Some (Code candidate)
```

This function contains the run-time logic that prevents clients from creating empty `Code` values:

```
> tryCreateCode "foo";;
val it : Code option = Some (Code "foo")
> tryCreateCode "";;
val it : Code option = None
> tryCreateCode "   ";;
val it : Code option = None
```

What prevents a client from creating an invalid `Code` value, then? For example, wouldn't a client be able to circumvent the `tryCreateCode` function and simply write `Code ""`?

This is where [signature files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233196.aspx) come in. You create a signature file (`.fsi`), and in that declare types and functions like this:

```
type Code
val tryCreateCode : string -> Code option
```

Here, the `Code` type is declared, but its 'constructor' isn't. This means that you can't directly create values of this types. This, for example, doesn't compile:

```
Code ""
```

The error given is:

> error FS0039: The value, constructor, namespace or type 'Code' is not defined

The only way to create a `Code` value is to use the `tryCreateCode` function.

As given here, you can no longer access the underlying string value of `Code`, unless you also provide a function for that:

```
let toString (Code x) = x
```

and declare it in the same `.fsi` file as above:

```
val toString : Code -> string
```

That may look like a lot of work, but is really only six lines of code, and three lines of type declaration (in the `.fsi` file).

Comment: Wouldn't making the type constructor private be an alternative? `type Code = private Code of string`

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis I didn't know you could do that :$ Thank you! That dispenses with the need for an `.fsi` file, but the rest of my answer still applies.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't convenient syntax for declaring a restricted subset of types but I would leverage active patterns to do this.  As you rightly say, you can make a type and check it's validity when you construct it:

```
/// String type which can't be null or whitespace
type FullString (string) =
    let string = 
        match (System.String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace string) with
        |true -> invalidArg "string" "string cannot be null or whitespace"
        |false -> string
    member this.String = string
```

Now, constructing this type naively may throw runtime exceptions and we don't want that!  So let's use active patterns:

```
let (|FullStr|WhitespaceStr|NullStr|) (str : string) =
    match str with
    |null -> NullStr
    |str when System.String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace str -> WhitespaceStr
    |str -> FullStr(FullString(str))
```

Now we have something that we can use with pattern matching syntax to build our `FullString`s.  This function is safe at runtime because we only create a `FullString` if we're in the valid case.

You can use it like this:

```
let printString str =
    match str with
    |NullStr -> printfn "The string is null"
    |WhitespaceStr -> printfn "The string is whitespace"
    |FullStr fstr -> printfn "The string is %s" (fstr.String)
```

Comment: Thanks for this example. I have two concerns: 1. I will have to use ".String" every time I use it somewhere which looks awkward. 2. I would have to override Equals and what not for this FullString type.

Comment: @Mikhail You could use a record instead of a class which would give you automatic structural comparison, equality, etc but you'd have to do a bit more trickery to make sure the record could never contain an invalid string.  That said, these overrides should be pretty straightforward since you can just redirect directly to string's methods.